# Frege's Notation for Part III of the Begriffsschrift

Tags: logic

There are a couple packages I know of for helping one to lay out Frege's notation, with a focus on that in *Basic Laws of Arithmetic* (*Grundgesetze der Arithmetik*): begriff, fge, grundgesetze. However, it seems that none of these handle the notation he developed for Part III of *Begriffsschrift* (& then abandoned for *Basic Laws*). I'm trying to figure out what the best way to layout something like the below might be:

[image]

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 7):

Once I typeset the Begriffsschrift and I had to solve the problem that
you describe too. I placed my solution in a package called [GFnotation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gfnotation)
(OK, it is not the best name) and you can find it on CTAN. It does not
only typeset the symbol called ``property F is hereditary in the
f-sequence'' but it can be used to handle all of Frege's notation in
the Begriffsschrift.

Have a look at my article in TUGboat: [``Typesetting the
`Begriffsschrift' by Gottlob Frege in plain TeX.''](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-3/tb114wermuth.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}
\[
    \makeatletter
    \BA@colsep=4pt
    \makeatother\begin{blockarray}{c(l}
  \alpha & F(\alpha )\\
  \rule[-1.5ex]{0.8pt}{3.5ex}\\
  \delta & f(\delta, \alpha )
  \end{blockarray} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Stack it!!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\Centerstack{\alpha \\ \vert\\ \delta}
\biggl(
\Centerstack[l]{F(\alpha) \\ \\ f(\delta,\alpha)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing!!! So natural.

Answer (score 4):

It ain't pretty, but perhaps this is a start of a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\halign{\hfil$\phantom{(}#$\hfil\cr\alpha\cr|\cr\delta\cr}}
    \!\bigg(
    \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\halign{$#$\hfil\cr F(\alpha)\cr\phantom{|}\cr f(\delta,\alpha)\cr}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might perhaps want to make this into a macro...

Answer (score 3):

Some simple solution, but with problem in alignment. Maybe could be combined with others to improve it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\Big\vert}
\newcommand{\frege}[2]{\foo_{#2}^{#1} \Biggr(_{f(#1,#2)}^{F(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\[ \foo_{\delta}^{\alpha} \Biggr(_{f(\alpha,\delta)}^{F(\alpha)} \]

\[ \frege{\alpha}{\delta} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]