# A typography challenge from over a hundred years ago

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, minipage, arrays, nesting

I am a newbie in LaTeX. I am now typesetting the formal proof from Begriffsschrift by Frege, which look like this:

[image: The foram proof from Begriff]

As seen in the picture, I decide to put all the elements of the proof into a 3x3 table. Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%load package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=1cm, tmargin=1cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, amsmath, amssymb, grundgesetze}

%set up counter

%set up command
\newcommand{\MP}{\noindent\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}}
\newcommand{\ThNum}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{l}{#1}\\}

%set up environment
\newenvironment{Frege}
 {\begin{tabular}{lcr}}{\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{Sub}
 {\begin{tabular}{r|l}}{\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{Begriff}
 {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Frege}
 \begin{Sub}
 \ThNum{1}
 $q$ &
 \setlength{\GGlinewidth}{10pt}\GGconditional{\GGterm{q}}{\GGterm{p}}\\
 $p$ &
 \setlength{\GGlinewidth}{10pt}\GGconditional{\GGterm{p}}
 {\GGconditional{\GGterm{q}}{\GGterm{p}}}\\
 \end{Sub}
 &
 \begin{Begriff}
 \setlength{\GGlinewidth}{10pt}\GGjudge\GGconditional{\GGterm{p}}
 {\GGconditional{\GGterm{q}}{\GGterm{p}}}
 \end{Begriff}
  & \\
 12 & \MP &\\
\end{Frege}

\end{document}
```

I use the macro `grundgesetze` to present the Frege's notation. I meet four  problems:

1. The first line of the minor premise and the number of it doesn't align on the same line. How can I make it is?
2. I put all the substitutions in a table in order to take the advantage of inserting a vertical line easily. But the disadvantage of it is all the content in table are being too small in size. How can I fix it? Or is there any other method to insert a vertical line easily?
3. The cell with the number of major premise suddenly expands and ruins all my arrangement. What's wrong with it? And how can I fix it?
4. I have no idea on how to put the number of conclusion (new theorem) in the exact location in cell. Would you mind give me some suggestion?

P.S. The current outcome after compling:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! As background, for typesetting this Begriffsschrift, apart from the LaTeX package `grundgesetze` which you seem to be using, have you looked at the LaTeX package `begriff`, and the plain-TeX package `GFnotation`? For the latter, see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366002/freges-notation-for-part-iii-of-the-begriffsschrift), and the article [Typesetting the “Begriffsschrift” by Gottlob Frege in plain TeX](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-3/tb114wermuth.pdf) by Udo Wermuth.

Comment: Not an answer or code, but an example showing that it's been done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463176/579